# JFrog Artifactory could not start artdb.db_properties' doesn't exist

Tags: artifactory

I've installed JFrog Artifactory on linux platform, configured to use an external mysql server.

I could see tables being created how ever the artifactory service throws page 500 exception.

looking at the catalina.out states that

**`Caused by: org.artifactory.storage.StorageException: Failed to load db properties from database`**

**`Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'artdb.db_properties' doesn't exist`**

need help guys!!  how do i get it resolved..

Comment: Does the db_properties table exist in the database?

Comment: Thanks @DrorBereznitsky , I've managed to get it working , by reinstalling the artifactory from scratch and somehow it has created the tables required..

Answer (score 0):

Connect to another database:

1. create new db in mysql
2. Correct system.yaml
3. Restart artifactory